# trying to use the same function with similar class names Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

hello I know you are not able to have similar ID tags because of the fact there will be a console error, but in my scenario, I am trying to have a modal display with different info in it similar buttons are clicked with the same class name

for example

```
   <div class="source">
     <h1 data-target="2"></h1>
     <button class="showBtn">BTN</button>
   </div>

   <div class="source">
     <h1 data-target="3"></h1>
     <button class="showBtn">BTN</button>
   </div>

   <div class="modal hide">
     <div id="modalOuput"></div>
   </div>
```

JS (I already have the modal showing up, my problem would be to have the modal display with unique identifiers in the modal also display for example)

```
     const modalOutput = document.querySelector('#modalOutput');
     const sourceData = document.querySelector('.source').getAttribute('data-target);

      modalOutput.textContent = sourceData
```

thank you

Comment: *I know you are not able to have similar ID tags because of the fact there will be a console error* You won't get a console error. You will just only ever locate the first one. Also, *similar* ids are fine, duplicate IDs are not.

Comment: @Scott Marcus yeah you’re right but in terms of trying to use the same function with duplicate class names is that possible ?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. But, you'll need to pinpoint which element is supposed to be affected and you can do that by locating it based on its parent.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#modalOutput").on('show.bs.modal', function(e){
    var button = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var dToPopulate = button.data('whatever');
    var modal = $(this);
    modal.find('.modal-body').html(dToPopulate);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="modalOutput" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body"><!-- data-whatever attribute of selected button--></div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

  <div class="source">
     <h1></h1>
     <button data-whatever="2" class="showBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalOutput">BTN</button>
   </div>

   <div class="source">
     <h1></h1>
     <button data-whatever="3" class="showBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalOutput">BTN</button>
   </div>
```

The code will select the value of data-whatever and put it into modalOutput.

Comment: I ran this code and it didn't have the second button work and the first button had both results show up in the same modal. When you ran the function for each I thought it was supposed to run separately and have the outputs be separated